# Permissions for pg_terminate_backend on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, permissions, rdbms, amazon-rds

I have a user `abc` on a PostgreSQL database on Amazon RDS. The user is a superuser as far as I can tell:

```
=> grant rds_superuser to abc;
NOTICE:  role "abc" is already a member of role "rds_superuser" GRANT ROLE
```

I try to kill some transactions, however I get:

```
=> select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity;
ERROR:  must be superuser or have the same role to terminate other server processes
```

I searched through the Amazon RDS docs extensively, however I still don't get it. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon chose a confusing name for their database administrator role. It is not, in fact, a superuser as far as PostgreSQL is concerned, which you can verify with:

```
SHOW is_superuser;
```

The actual PostgreSQL superuser access level is not available in RDS, because it'd let you "break out" of the database system by loading your own code, modifying files directly, etc.

So you can't use superuser-only functions in RDS  unless Amazon provides a `SECURITY DEFINER` wrapper function for it, or exposes an AWS API call to let you invoke that functionality indirectly.

However, in this case, you only read half the error message:

> ERROR:  must be superuser **or have the same role** to terminate other server processes

Your SQL tries to terminate *every* connection to the DB, because it has no `WHERE` clause. And some of those connections must be with different user roles, but you're not a superuser, so you can't do that.

You can still terminate connections from your own username, though.

Comment: Oh snap. Indeed I confirmed that the problem was with attempting to terminate transactions owned by other users than `abc`.