# Assign privileges to a postgres user

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am working on creating a postgres user and assign certain privileges to the user. These are privileges to execute certain functions with the end goal of being able to replicate data or change-data-capture.

Specifically, I am looking at the `system privilege` column of the postgres row in the table - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html

I am running into issues granting execute privileges here. For example -
`grant execute on routine pg_terminate_backend() to <db_user>;`

This returns an error - `function pg_terminate_backend() does not exist` However, I am able to query it in `information_schema.routines` table.

What would be the right to grant the privileges to a db user. I tried creation of a role and grant privileges but it shows the same error.

Comment: Seems to overlap somewhat with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713375/permissions-for-pg-terminate-backend-on-amazon-rds

Leave out the () from the GRANT statement to avoid the "does not exist" error. If there are still problems, the details from that other post might help.